# "E: Unable to locate package php8.0-common" when trying to install, and after adding its ppa

Tags: kali-linux, php

I would like to install php8 on debian ( kali linux ) and use it for many years. There is a problem: when I run the following commands i cant find php8 just 7.4

**the commands**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php # Press enter when prompted.
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates wget -y
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg 
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
sudo apt update

sudo apt install php8.0-common php8.0-cli -y
```

**to get this output**

```
E: Unable to locate package php8.0-common 
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0-common' 
E: Unable to locate package php8.0-cli 
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0-cli'
```

Comment: Kali is designed for experts doing security stuff, and for masochists. PHP is for word-press (one one else much uses it any more) and masochists. Consider a different Gnu/Linux distro, and consider moustache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found a solution ( Change the Distribution from software and updates To buster )
because it's kali-rolling and it's not found